# Question closed as Dupe (Xmen Sentinel Question)

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[If the "Sentinel" Program existed since 1973 why it was never mentioned in the original trilogy of X-Men?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59825/if-the-sentinel-program-exists-in-1973-why-it-was-never-mentioned-in-the-origina) was closed as duplicate because of the answer in [What timeline is the post-credit scene at the end of The Wolverine in?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56921/what-timeline-is-the-post-credit-scene-at-the-end-of-the-wolverine-in)

Yet the q and a in that question do not address the new question's,er, question. What gives.

Comment: If you don’t think it’s a dupe but it’s been closed as such, then the best thing to do is to edit your question to explain why the answers on the claimed dupe don’t answer your new question.

Comment: @alexwlchan not my question, but also it amounts to "the q/a doesn't answer the question".

Comment: Hence a comment, not an answer. I don’t know why Keen closed as dupe, but that sort of edit is usually the way to get un-closed.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't VTC, but I would.

From the original question:

> If we assume that the post-credit scene is in the Days of Future Past timeline, then we are left to explain why no mutants have are being hunted by Sentinels already.

I'll rephrase this for you: if the post-credit scene after *The Wolverine* is in the same timeline/continuity as the original X-Men movies, why is there no indication of the existence of Sentinels hunting mutants?

The answer to the question (which is not accepted, but not necessarily wrong) mentions that the Sentinels *were* planned to appear, but were ultimately cut (or arguably reduced to a head in the Danger Room).

IMO, the question has not been answered satisfactorily, but the question is a dupe.

Comment: Indeed, they're both about the issue of there not being Sentinels in the original 3 X-Men films.

Comment: It's also wrong, as can be seen by my answer.

Comment: @cde Regardless of whether or not the answer is correct, the question has been asked already. Correctness has no bearing on whether or not something is marked as a dupe.

Comment: @cde phantom42's question does *way* more research on the subject to outline the jarring lack of Sentinels in the original trilogy, that police were called in *X-Men 2* instead of Sentinels being the most egregious IMO.  Both cover the exact same issue, in the original films, Sentinels aren't these omnipresent threat to mutants as the history of the bleak future stated them to be.